# how do I add items to listview dynamically in android

Tags: java, android

Can anybody help me? I'm trying to create a ListView in Android, and I'm trying to load items into it using code (not using XML)

Here's the code that I have so far

```
tweetList = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.tweetListView);
        TextView tv;
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("I'm a textView");
            tweetList.addHeaderView(tv);

        }

        tweetList.invalidate();
```

What am I doing wrong? The items are not showing in runtime

EDIT: I changed the code as per the answers below and here's the code I have now

```
 tweetList = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.tweetListView);
        ArrayAdapter<TextView> aa = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, R.id.tweetListView);
        tweetList.setAdapter(aa);
        TextView tv;
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("I'm a textView");
            //tweetList.addHeaderView(tv);

            aa.add(tv);

        }

        tweetList.invalidate();
```

I'm getting an exception now

```
11-10 01:32:16.002: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(867): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050030 type #0x12 is not valid
```

Why am I not able to add them dynamically now?

Comment: Now you supply a id field to arrayAdapter, while it should be a layout item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `ArrayAdapter` and add it to the `ListView`. Then just add elements to the `ArrayAdapter` dynamically.

For example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
tweetList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
// ...
arrayAdapter.add("New Item");
```

Comment: THANKS DUDE, you ROCK!!!!! I had a mistake in the declaration of the Adapter, once fixed the adapter is working now

Comment: Now I have another issue, I'm trying to add TextViews to the ListView, is that even possible like we do in WPF? now all the items in the listview appear as 'android.widget.textview@someID'

Comment: @user974038 try `ArrayAdapter<TextView>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: What is 'context' out here??
Because 'this' doesn't work because it is not of type android.content.Context

Answer (score 0):

The header view is just a header, its not the items in the list. Your listview receives its contents through an *Adapter*. The `ListView` does not keep `Views` for its children, but its the adaptor who creates them and fills them with the appropiate data when they need to be shown at the screen. Search for basic tutorials on how to do this, there are lots out there; and remember adapters are the key.