# Setting ListView Adaptor: Null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to set the contents of a ListView to an array of TextViews.

With what I have currently I get a Null Pointer Exception, even though I think I'd doing what is suggested here:
[how do I add items to listview dynamically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073018/how-do-i-add-items-to-listview-dynamically-in-android)

Here's what I have currently:

```
ListView lvSuggestions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSuggestions);

ArrayAdapter<TextView> arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
lvSuggestions.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

But I get the exception when it sets the adaptor.

I've tried filling the ArrayList with TextViews and then creating the Adaptor with the full ArrayList, but I get the same Null Pointer Exception when I set the Adaptor.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this links for usage of custom adapters.

[LINK1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

[LINK2](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6816874&q=binding-android-listview-with-custom-objects-using-arrayadapter)

[LINK3](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)

[LINK4](https://gist.github.com/721932)

[LINK5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958279/how-to-use-a-custom-arrayadapter-in-a-separate-class)

[LINK6](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<TextView> arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

change the above line with below

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

and add all the string that you want to display to arrayAdapter as below

```
arrayAdapter.add("string1");
arrayAdapter.add("string2");
arrayAdapter.add("string3");//so on
```

Comment: But I don't want to fill it with Strings. Can I not fill it with TextViews?

Comment: even in textview you need to settext with strings

Comment: Yeah, I know I would need to set the Textview text with strings. But I want my ListView to contain an array of TextViews, because I want to be able to set the id's of the TextViews.

Is it possible to fill a ListView with an ArrayList of type TextView?

Comment: but how will you settext and id to arrayadapter and what the use of setting ids to textview in your case

Comment: With something like the following: 
TextView txtArtistName = new TextView(this);
txtArtistName.setId(1);
txtArtistName.setText("test");
arrayAdapter.add(txtArtistName);

Comment: posted an one more answer go through that links.

Comment: @Tom: Agarwal's answer is the correct way use an `ArrayAdapter` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which (for all intents and purposes) simply defines a `TextView` per list item. There is no need to have a different `id` for each `TextView` in this case - if a user selects (clicks) the list view item you can simply retrieve the text from there.

Comment: I wanted to set the id, as I have "hidden" text that I would like to retrieve on click. It's a unique key for the text that is displayed. And I would like to know which key has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSuggestions);
```

might return `null` if `findViewById` returns `null` (no item is found) or the returned object is not of type `ListView`.

Protect it with:

```
if (lvSuggestions != null) {
  ArrayAdapter<TextView> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, 
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
  lvSuggestions.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: While you are right, it's not that line that is returning the exception. It's the:
lvSuggestions.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: yes, `lvSuggestions.setAdapter()` will throw a NullPointerException if `lvSuggestions` is `null`

Comment: Ah, I understand. But it isn't null. I can see that in Debugging.

Comment: Then go with Agarval's answer (I'm not knowledgable enough with the inner workings of androuid :)), but I suggest you put the protective if there anyway: can save you from future problems

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you put setContentView after setAdapter.

it must be like that:

setContentView(xxx);

//....

setAdapter(xxx)

Hope it help!